# angular2-seed-advanced: got RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript, angular2-seed

I'm trying to run unchanged [angular-seed-advanced](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced) project on different platforms. Web and desktop(linux/windows) compiled and ran ok, but when I tried to run it on android(emulator and real device) I got the following error:

```
Successfully deployed on device with identifier 'emulator-5554'.
JS: ns-renderer: ERROR BOOTSTRAPPING ANGULAR
JS: ns-renderer: Maximum call stack size exceeded
JS: 
JS: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
JS:     at ScanSubscriber.Subscriber [as constructor] (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.js:31:24)
JS:     at new ScanSubscriber (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/scan.js:79:16)
JS:     at ScanOperator.call (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/scan.js:67:33)
JS:     at AnonymousSubject.Observable.subscribe (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:22)
JS:     at ScanOperator.call (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/scan.js:67:23)
JS:     at AnonymousSubject.Observable.subscribe (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:22)
JS:     at ScanOperator.call (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/scan.js:67:23)
JS:     at AnonymousSubject.Observable.subscribe (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:22)
JS:     at ScanOperator.call (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/rxjs/operator/scan.js:67:23)
JS:     at AnonymousSubject.Observable.subscribe (/data/data/com.yourdomain.appname/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js:42:22)
```

[image: emulator screenshot]

Can someone help or give me a hint where to look for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author updated the code to fix this, so the error gone and android app now works correct.